# Resizing Rectangle Shifts Location

Tags: c#, wpf

What could be causing this strange behavior in the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ANRrDuV563c)? I'm trying to resize a rectangle. When the mouse moves smoothly, everything seems to work as it should. I have no ideas at all.

```
public void HandleMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  if (isResizing)
  {
    Point newPoint = Mouse.GetPosition(MainCanvas);

    double left = Canvas.GetLeft(editor.SelectedArea);
    double top = Canvas.GetTop(editor.SelectedArea);
    double width = editor.SelectedArea.Width;
    double height = editor.SelectedArea.Height;

    double diffX = (newPoint.X - startPoint.X);
    double diffY = (newPoint.Y - startPoint.Y);

    switch (currentCorner)
    {
      case Corner.RM:
        double newWidth = width + diffX;
        if (newWidth < 0)
        {
          currentCorner = Corner.LM;
        }
        else
        {
          editor.SelectedArea.Width = newPoint.X - left;
        }
        break;

      case Corner.LM:
        double newLeft = left + diffX;
        double newWidthLm = width - diffX;
        if (newWidthLm < 0)
        {
          currentCorner = Corner.RM;
        }
        else
        {
          Canvas.SetLeft(editor.SelectedArea, newPoint.X);
          editor.SelectedArea.Width = width + (left - newPoint.X);
        }
        break;
      }
      startPoint = newPoint;
```

Comment: You should be getting position from the sender object and not directly from the Canvas.   Use something like : var canvas = sender as Control.  This will always get the same point while executing. The mouse is moving while code is executing so when you get Canvas you are getting a different point as you execute.  You want the same point while executing the method HandleMouseMove.  What is "startPoint"?  Is SelectedArea changing while method is executing?

Comment: Also, when the width becomes negative, you should probably adjust the X position of the rectangle and make its width positive. Otherwise you introduce an error of diffX.

Comment: @jdweng startPoint = Mouse.GetPosition(MainCanvas) in HandleMouseDown method. SelectedArea is a rectangle whose size must be changed during method execution. The video shows the effect I'm trying to achieve. And everything works well if the mouse moves smoothly. It seems to me that some code is missing in - if (newWidth < 0) {..}

Comment: No, No, No.  You want the locations to be static while executing the method HandleMouseMove().  Suppose you have 4 apples on the table and you have a method that adds one to the number.  While you are executing the method somebody places another apple on the table.  Do you want sometimes to get an answer 5 and sometimes an answer 6?  You want the results to always be the same which is when the method is called.  Not what changes in the middle of executing.

Comment: It would be kind to upvote a *correct* answer to honor the effort. Don't take a person's time for granted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the new width becomes negative, we have the problem that we cannot simply move the current edge as usual, as this would create a rectangle with a negative width. Therefore, instead of moving the current edge, we must move the other one.

```cs
switch (currentCorner)
{
    case Corner.RM:
        double newWidth = width + diffX;
        if (newWidth < 0)
        {
            newWidth = -newWidth;
            editor.SelectedArea.X -= newWidth;
            editor.SelectedArea.Width = newWidth;
            currentCorner = Corner.LM;
        }
        else
        {
            editor.SelectedArea.Width = newWidth;
        }
        break;
    case Corner.LM:
        double newLeft = left + diffX;
        double newWidthLm = width - diffX;
        if (newWidthLm < 0)
        {
            newWidthLm = -newWidthLm;
            editor.SelectedArea.X = editor.SelectedArea.Right;
            editor.SelectedArea.Width = newWidthLm;
            currentCorner = Corner.RM;
        }
        else
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(editor.SelectedArea, newPoint.X);
            editor.SelectedArea.Width = newWidthLm;
        }
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When moving things around I would recommend only using the state when the drag operation started, and the current mouse position. Using intermediate states and deltas can result in rounding errors and other weirdness.

So a program might look something like this pseudo code:

```
public void OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){
    if(ClickedCorner(e)){
        state = States.Dragging;
        startPosition = Mouse.GetPosition(MainCanvas);
        currentCorner = GetCorner(startPosition);
        startRectangle = GetCurrentRectangle();
        cornerOffset = startRectangle.GetCornerPosition(currentCorner) - startPosition ;
    }
}

public void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){
    if(state == States.Dragging){
         var newPosition = Mouse.GetPosition(MainCanvas);
         var newCornerPosition = newPosition  + cornerOffset;
         var newRectangle = startRectangle.WithCornerPosition(currentCorner, newCornerPosition );
         UpdateUiRectangle(newRectangle);
    }
}
public void OnMouseUp(){
    state = States.Idle;
}
```

This should ensure that no weirdness can be going on.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved in the following way - at the moment of transition from right to left, I reset the value of the rectangle width to zero. When moving from left to right, the width is also reset to zero and additionally the left border of the shape is shifted to left + width. Not the brightest idea, but it works.

```
switch (currentCorner)
 {
     case Corner.MiddleRight:
         double newWidthMR = width + diffX;
         if (newWidthMR < 0)
         {
             editor.SelectedArea.Width = 0;
             currentCorner = Corner.MiddleLeft;
         }
         else
         {
             editor.SelectedArea.Width = newPoint.X - left;
         }
         break;

     case Corner.MiddleLeft:
         double newWidthML = width - diffX;
         if (newWidthML < 0)
         {
             currentCorner = Corner.MiddleRight;
             editor.SelectedArea.Width = 0;
             Canvas.SetLeft(editor.SelectedArea, left + width);
         }
         else
         {
             Canvas.SetLeft(editor.SelectedArea, newPoint.X);
             editor.SelectedArea.Width = width + (left - newPoint.X);
         }
         break;
```